# Swift regular expression for arabic decimals in arabic text

Tags: ios, swift, regex, arabic

I have some Arabic text which has some decimals as well.
for example this text

"بِسۡمِ اللّٰہِ الرَّحۡمٰنِ الرَّحِیۡمِ ﴿۱﴾"

"وَاِذَا قِیۡلَ لَہُمۡ اٰمِنُوۡا کَمَاۤ اٰمَنَ النَّاسُ قَالُوۡۤا اَنُؤۡمِنُ کَمَاۤ اٰمَنَ السُّفَہَآءُ ؕ اَلَاۤ اِنَّہُمۡ ہُمُ السُّفَہَآءُ وَلٰکِنۡ لَّا یَعۡلَمُوۡنَ ﴿۱۴﴾"

This text has verse numbers as Arabic digits in the end.
I wanted to find out all the matches for the verse numbers in these verses.

In swift I am tring to use the regular expression but somehow i am not coming up with the correct regex.

Here is my code:

```
func getRegex() {
    // unicode for the arabic digits    
    let regexStr = "[\u{0660}-\u{0669}]+"
    //let regexStr = "[\\p{N}]+"
    //let regexStr = "[۹۸۷۶۵۴۳۲۱۰]+"
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regexStr, options: .caseInsensitive)
        let matches = regex.matches(in: self.arabicText, options: .anchored, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.arabicText.count))
        print("Matches count : \(matches.count)")
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Can somebody guide me on how I can get the matches for the Arabic digits in the example Arabic text?

Comment: Do not use `.anchored` and use `arabicText.utf16.count`. `regex.matches(in: arabicText, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: arabicText.utf16.count)`

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

The `.anchored` argument makes the pattern only match at the start of string, so you need to remove it.

Also, as your string is not ASCII, you need to use `self.arabicText.utf16.count` string property rather than accessing the `self.arabicText.count` directly.

So, you can use

```swift
let regexStr = "[۹۸۷۶۵۴۳۲۱۰]+"
```

and then

```swift
let matches = regex.matches(in: self.arabicText, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.arabicText.utf16.count))
```